# Python OCR , rotate image to align horizontally (Straight line)

Tags: python, rotation, ocr, image-recognition

This is example:
[image]

Is it any possible way to rotate the image to make this box/table to be aligned horizontally?

Comment: For the general idea: Mask the table header ("Balances"), e.g. by color/grayvalue thresholding, get the minimum area (rotated) rectangle (cf. OpenCV's `minAreaRect`), get the rotation angle from that, and rotate the image using that angle (maybe by using Pillow or scikit-image). If you have a specific problem implementing that, please provide a [mre].

Comment: To provide minimal reproducible example need to understand is this is even possible, I found a way how to rotate an image by using pytesseract. WIll try to do it.. and if will face a problem will update this question.